# JasmineReporter JUnitXmlReporter overwrites the results of the run

Tags: xml, junit, jasmine, protractor

My specs share the same first describes (the second is different) e.g.

**spec1.js:**

```
describe("topic1",()=> {
  describe("testcase1",()=> {
   ...
  });
});
```

**spec2.js:**

```
describe("topic1",()=> {
  describe("testcase2",()=> {
   ...
  });
});
```

which works fine if I run the both specs in the same browser like:

```
protractor --specs spec1.js,spec2.js config.js
```

But as I want to restart the browser between runs of spec1.js and spec2.js with either:

```
protractor --specs spec1.js config.js; protractor --specs spec2.js config.js
```

or setting in capabilites:

```
shardTestFiles: true
```

then the `junitresults.xml` resp. `junitresults-topic1.xml` (depending on `consolidateAll` option being`true` or `false`) is generated containing only the results of the last spec (spec2.js) run.

How can I get all the runs in my XML results?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering Protractor twice to avoid using the same browser session, I would suggest using the option - `restartBrowserBetweenTests`. Check out the below extract from [Protractor official documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L483).

> /**    * If true, protractor will restart the browser between each
>   test. Default    * value is false.*/

```
  restartBrowserBetweenTests?: boolean;
```

This will help you avoid the problem of jUnit XML report getting overwritten.

Comment: unfortunately, restarting after each test (it) is too much, I wish to restart after each spec.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with our builds. They ran fine, but we would only get the number of results based on the "maxInstances" parameter. We use both the jUnit XML and the pretty reporter. What we did to fix this was add "isSharded: true" to the pretty reporter and "shardOnSpec: true" to the multiCapabilites. Here is an example:

```
let prettyReporter = new PrettyReporter({
  path: dirPath,
  screenshotOnPassed: false,
  isSharded: true
});

multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ["--window-size=1920x1080"]
    },
    shardTestFiles: true,
    shardOnSpec: true,
    maxInstances: 4,
  }],
```

We run our CI/CD in Azure DevOps and this allowed all tests run to be processed by the reporter. So now we get all our test results instead of just the last 4.

Hope this helps.